# Using automatic x-axis plotting in R with a fixed offset

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot a simple line in R e.g.,

```
plot(numbers, main="My numbers", ylab="Count", xlab="Ticks", type="l")
```

But as I am using a smoothed average I want the labels for the xaxis to start at a fixed offset (200,000 - I am literally plotting hundreds of millions of points) but want to be flexible I can use the automatic ticks provided by R and not have to calculate the appropriate ticks every time I update the data set.

To be clear, I have several hundred million observations and I want the first to be labelled as 200,000 and the subsequent ticks to be automatically placed.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? Anyone like to tell me?

Comment: Why not `xlim = c(200000, 300000)` ? Expected output is not very clear, do you mind editing your post, maybe add expected image?

Comment: Because I am not seeking to drop the first 200,000 observations, merely rebase the axis so that observation 1 = 200,000 - I can't add the expected image because I don't know how to generate it - but it's a simple line plot with x axis labels starting at 200,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can set the `x` starting index at `N`, see example:

```
# example reproducible data
set.seed(1); numbers <- data.frame(y = runif(20))

# add index at selected start number
# my new start
N = 200000
numbers$x <- N + seq(nrow(numbers)) - 1

plot(x = numbers$x, y = numbers$y,
     main = "My numbers - SUBSET", ylab = "Count", xlab = "Ticks", type = "l")
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want a subset. I want the first point to be labelled as 200,000 and then the 10th to be 200,009 and the one millionth to be 1,199,999 and so on

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
plot(numbers, Title="My numbers", ylab="Count", xlab="Ticks", type="l", xaxt="none")
axis(1, seq(200000,<insert max here>, <insert increment here>))
```

You have to build the axis labels yourself.  There's no getting around that.

Comment: Please consider using **edit** to update posts or **delete** posts that are no longer relevant. No need to "sigh" as you said the Q was not clear and made your answer irrelevant, maybe the reason for downvote, simply delete or edit your post.